minor ticks using numpy and pandas to plot
How can I add minor ticks to a plot that is done using numpy?
I have a file with two columns A and B, I need to multiply each by a different factor using numpy, and I want to plot them (there are several files and I want to plot all of them in subplots) with minor ticks, but numpy has no attribute for minor ticks.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fig, plt= plt.subplots(7,1, sharex=True,figsize=(5,12))
file = pd.read_csv('file1.txt',header=0,delimiter= '\s+', index_col=False)
plt[0].plot(file.A.multiply(33.4),file.B.multiply(1/144))

I tried :
plt.setx.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
to plot the minor ticks every 5 values.

NumPy has no attributes for any sort of ticks. You will have better luck looking in the Matplotlib documentation. (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/major_minor_demo.html#major-and-minor-ticks). To encourage a full answer, consider adding example data to make your code fully executable.

I now about numpy, but I am using pandas to read a big piece of data, and numpy to do the operations for each column, how to add this file here?

you can directly access the x-axis in each subplot of the figure and apply the set_minor_locator function.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5, 12))

for i in range(7):
    file = pd.read_csv(f'file{i+1}.txt', header=0, delimiter='\s+', index_col=False)
    axs[i].plot(file.A.multiply(33.4), file.B.multiply(1/144))
    axs[i].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))

plt.show()


Then again is not possible to do this beacuse of numpy:  'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
